# Permutation generator function F#

Tags: f#, permutation

I need to generate a list of all distinct permutations of 1..n x 1..n where teh first value does not equal the second
(i.e. generate 3 -> [(3,2):: (3,1):: (2,3) ::(2,1)::(1,3)::(1,2)]

the exact scenario is you have a pool of objects(cards) and one is dealt to each player. If a player is dealt a card, no other player can be dealt that card(ignore suits for the time being, if I have to I will make a lut for 1-52 to map to the actual cards)

I came up with the following which seems messy at best

```
 let  GenerateTuples (numcards: int) =
    let rec cellmaker (cardsleft: int) (cardval:int) = 
        if cardval = cardsleft  then (if cardval <= 0  then []  else cellmaker cardsleft (cardval-1) ) elif cardval <= 0  then [] else (cardsleft, cardval) :: cellmaker cardsleft (cardval-1)
    let rec generatelists (cardsleft:int) =
        cellmaker cardsleft numcards @ (if cardsleft > 1 then generatelists (cardsleft-1) else [])
    generatelists numcards
```

is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily using list comprehensions:

```
let GenerateTuples (n:int) =
    [for i in 1..n do for j in 1..n do if i <> j then yield (i,j)]
```

Comment: According to my tests his implementation is about 13 times faster. Even if I am off by a lot that is nothing to sneeze at.

Comment: thanks, I knew there had to be something smarter, now to go figure out how list comprehensions work...

Comment: Agreed about the times. There is little difference for small n, but with n > 200, the functional solution (ie. the OP code) is 4 to 5 times faster. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is best seen as a matrix problem, and the nested "for" loops of the imperative solution can be done functionally.

```
let Permute n =
let rec Aux (x,y) =
    if (x,y) = (n,n) then
        []
    else
        let nextTuple = if y = n then ((x + 1),1) else (x,(y + 1))
        if x = y then
            Aux nextTuple
        else
            (x,y)::(Aux nextTuple)
Aux (1,1)
```

This is not tail-recursive, so get's a stack overflow at approx n = 500, on my machine. It is almost trivial to make this function tail recursive.

The times for this were very interesting. This function (tail recursive version) took 50% more than the original, and the imperative solution took approx 3 times as long again! Yes - the original functional solution is the fastest, this is the next fastest, and the imperative list comprehension was the slowest, by approx 1::1.5::4. Tested on a wide variety of datasets.

Comment: From what I can see the functional and the list comprehension solution diverge, quite violently. I don't understand quite why the pure functional w/tail recursion optimization is so fast, at n = 5000 it was more than a factor of 10 better, whereas at n = 500, it was closer to a factor of 3 better. I need to look at the reflected code...

Comment: Thanks, user442895. I've just done Project Euler problem 1, with a simple tail recursive function, and found that the F# solutions on the net use a list comprehension. The times for the functional solution were about 8 times better than the list comprehensions.